# Connect to SQL Server with Windows Authentication using DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, ntlm, dbeaver

I'm using Dbeaver on macOs Big Sur 11.6.1, trying to connect SQL Server with domain/windows auth(NTLM) but its getting error;

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. ClientConnectionId:14e96772-fd07-45ef-aefb-7816713f7723

I can successfully connect to different database with standart sql auth on domain. Its problem with windows auth/domain auth. But I can connect to db with windows auth on virtual machine.

> Authentication method : Windows Authentication - DBeaver Version : Version 21.3.1.xx

Connection settings;

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your connection settings? You probably need to request a Kerberos ticket from the KDC, unless the server is not in a domain

Comment: how can i connect with kerberos with url?

Comment: @charlieface hi i have edited the post for connection settings.

Comment: Instead of just `Username` try `YOURDOMAIN\Username` or `Username@yourdomainFQDN.whatever`

Comment: i hv try this but still cant connect :( @charlieface

Comment: All about system language, its RESOLVED by setting system language to english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the system language. After setting my system language to English, it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was getting the below error when trying to connect to an sql server. The error turned out to be due to expired password. Make sure you re-enter and check your password is correct (the password is masked, so it goes unnoticed).
[image]